# How to change the account for Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I use two Google accounts and add them to . Let's say acc1 and acc2. When I try to buy an app in the Market, it chooses acc1's Checkout account, and I don't see an option to change to acc2. Can I use acc2 to pay this? And I still want acc1 as the main account for other purposes. (i.e. Talk, Mail, contacts)

Possibly related question: [How Do I Know Which Google Account is Used for the Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-do-i-know-which-google-account-is-used-for-the-market)

Comment: I'm pretty certain the first Google account you add to your phone is the one that links with checkout.  As far as I know, you cannot change it (aside from removing both accounts and re-adding them in the opposite order).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of mid-2011 the Android Market supports multiple accounts.

> To add another account... Press <kbd>menu</kbd> button –
>   select settings – Accounts and Sync – tap on “Add account” and add
>   your another gmail account. To activate or use another gmail account
>   in the market, open the new market app (v 3.0.26) and select
>   “Accounts”. A list will pop-up showing all your gmail accounts that
>   you’ve added in “Accounts and Sync”. Select the one of your choice and
>   you’re good to go.

From http://www.theandroidsoul.com/multiple-accounts-sign-in-logins-supported-in-the-latest-android-market-v3-0-26/

Comment: How is this accomplished on KitKat Google Play account?

Answer (score 5):

[P.T. details](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market/14182#14182) how to accomplish this by simply adding another account to the phone and then selecting it in [Google Play Store settings](https://play.google.com/store/account).

It's worth noting that *originally* the only way to change the Google Account associated with the Google Play Store was to do a factory reset of your phone and set it up again from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three option, but 2nd and 3rd maybe works better xD

- You can go to Settings/Applications And CLEAR DATA to **Android Market app** and  **Google Services Framework**
- Or you can try to go to Settings/Accounts & Sync click on your account and hit on Remove Account Button
- Or try to clear data in the Gmail program, it should ask for a new account xD

That should unlink your account from the system and will ask you again for an Account to link to the system.

But take care on this because can be erased/lost some of your data as Conctacts associated with the previously added accout, also Email and Talk

Mainly because you are changing your linked account and those services use info from that linked account.

Comment: *"Or try to clear data in the Gmail program, it should ask for a new account"* - no I tried that... Apparently, the Gmail app just asks the Android Market app or Google Services Framework for the account name again...