# Android How to set new default user for Android Marketplace

Tags: google-play-store, accounts

I have a Sprint Samsung Captivate phone, and I am somewhat sharing it with co-worker.  Problem is that every time I want to download an app free or otherwise, her username comes up and prompts for password.  I would like to add own email and download under that without removing her account.  Much easier said than done.  I cannot seem to get her logged out and a new prompt for username and password where I could enter my user name.  This is a much tougher problem than I ever imagined.

Comment: I am open to all options here including deleting marketplace accounts and re-adding if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this.  You would need to entirely remove your account (the primary phone account) from the phone and add hers as the primary account, which would perform a factory reset on the phone.  Hopefully future versions of the Android OS will support multiple users, especially the tablet versions, but currently it does not.