# Multiple Android Market Accounts on a Single Device?

Tags: google-play-store

Is it possible to have multiple Android Market accounts on a Single phone?

If so, how do I do that?

(I have been able to add a second Gmail account, but I couldn't find any option to add a second Android Market account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, at least not as of now.  You can factory reset your device to remove the first account you set up (on some devices, you can just remove all the accounts without the reset) and then add the other one first, if you would like to use it instead. But if you actively want to use both, you're stuck.

Comment: Ouch! So how am I supposed to test [LVL integration](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#server-response-codes) with my application? This is the 2nd [Catch 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365118/market-licensing-example-always-getting-licensed) in Google's LVL scheme. I can understand how Google could release such a half-baked solution, but then why force developers to use LVL if they want to make their paid Applications available in **the** Android market? Thanks + 1 + accepting.

Comment: @an00b Good question. Hopefully Android 4.0 will address this problem!

Comment: This is so frustrating, because Google clearly instructs in the [Edit Profile](http://market.android.com/publish/editProfile) page to enter additional Gmail addresses for testing purposes. But these additional Gmail addresses cannot have Market accounts... and I can "buy" the application from myself (for testing purposes) but I can only do it once! So I can't really test upgrades... See the Catch 22?

Comment: I believe that it's not an OS version problem, but rather the facilities provided on http://market.android.com/publish  I can understand Google not wanting to provide more than one Market account per device **for security reasons**.

Comment: This is no longer valid. See: [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4955/16575)

Comment: Sure. It was not meant to criticize your answer (it was perfectly fine at that time), but rather meant as "follow-up" for those getting here with the same problem. Feel free to include that hint directly with your answer :)