# How to remove Google Account that is set for Android Market in device?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

In my Device I have entered the the xyz@gmail.com as google account and I have also set that account as the Market account.
Now I want to use abc@gmail.com as my market account but I am not able to do that. 
So how to set that another account for the android market.

I also want to remove the account xyz@gmail.com from my device completely. That Account I have set at the First time in to my device and now I am not able to remove it from the Device.

So what should I have to do for it?

Comment: If you only want to change the account you use for the Market, and don't need to remove your current primary account from your phone, then see also this question: [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't currently remove the primary Google account that you used to set up your Android device, the quickest way to switch to your new Google account would be to restore factory defaults and set up your device to use the new account.

The location of the factory reset depends on the Android version of the device. On ICS (4.0+) devices it's in `Settings` -> `Backup & reset` -> `Factory data reset`. On Honeycomb (3.x) devices it's in `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Factory data reset`. The same goes for Froyo + Gingerbread (2.0-2.3.x) if i remember correctly.

Note that this will **clear your apps and their data**, and depending on your device, *MAY* wipe your **internal and/or external SD card**, as TryTryAgain mentioned.

Comment: _Note that this will clear your apps and their data, but won't clear your internal or external SD card._ isn't entirely true. Many phones come with an option to wipe the SD as well. This, if I remember correctly, is the default option sometimes too. So, be careful and be sure not to COMPLETELY wipe everything.

Comment: @TryTryAgain OK, thanks for the info, will add to the answer. I've only used Samsung's and Google's devices, which don't wipe the SD from here.

Answer (score 1):

as GAThrawn said, you just need to add another google account in Options -> Accounts&Sync, and in Google Play application press Menu -> Accounts and link it to this new-linked account..

Comment: That does not remove it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on the home screen, click the Menu Key, then choose 'Settings', select 'Accounts and sync', click on the account which you want to remove, and finally press 'Remove Account' ... no big deal, no factory reset :)