# How do I change the Gmail account associated with the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the account for Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market)

I got on the market yesterday and it made me enter my password for my existing Google account but I had forgotten the password. I made a new one and tried to delete the old one but it wouldn't let me. I can't install apps now because I don't have the password. How can I set it to use the new account?

Comment: If you specifically want to remove it (rather than switching accounts in the Play Store) then perhaps take a look at [How to remove Google Account that is set for Android Market in device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18823/how-to-remove-google-account-that-is-set-for-android-market-in-device?lq=1)