# Locked out of Playstore

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Play Store locked me out saying "Couldn't log in. This account has been disabled."

This because Play Store required that I create a Gmail account, which I did, but then I was unsuccessful in logging in to the Gmail account.

I have a HUAWEI-M931, Android ver 4.0.4.

Comment: Why can't you login to the account?

Comment: Maybe you have incorrect password?

Comment: Can you log in to the account from elsewhere, such as a desktop browser? Is the account on your device? Does it sync?

Comment: I think you are not using the correct login information. You should try myusername@gmail.com as well as just myusername when you try to login.

Comment: I don't remember what the userid is. And the error message does not display it either. When I set up the phone and tried to use PlayStore, I used an older email account and have forgotten the username. At this point, my question is: can I uninstall PlayStore, and then somehow get it restored, with the hope that a clean install will let me start over with another email address? Or perhaps someone has another solution. Maybe a factory restore?

Comment: OK, i found the account I used. When I try to login (using the PC) it says Your account was disabled due to a violation of our Terms of Service and is no longer eligible to be reinstated. Well, I never even got to use the account, so I have no idea where that comes from. Am I banned from PlayStore for all eternity?

Comment: OK, is there another way to get apps installed on my Android phone?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution thanks to 'Related' items which show up in green on the right side of this page, such as ["How to change android primary google account"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18823/how-to-remove-google-account-that-is-set-for-android-market-in-device), and other related threads. I went to Settings, Accounts and Sync, clicked on the gmail account, Remove Account, then Add Account, at which point I entered my existing gmail account (the one that I know the password for) and when I went to  PlayStore it opened and I am now in.
Thank you.