# How to change Android's primary Google account

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-store, google-account

During the "in-app purchase" I am unable to switch the Google account I would like to use for "in-app purchase".

Currently, in order to change the primary Google account on Android operating system, we have the following ways:

1. Perform factory reset on our devices.
2. Remove other Google accounts, leave only one Google account.

If we perform factory reset, we will lose all data that we have not backed up or unable to do backup. And, we have to re-install the applications that we need to use.

If we choose to remove other Google accounts from our systems and leave only one Google account, if there are applications installed from Google Play Store by using the Google account that we want to remove from our systems, then we will not be able to remove the account from the system unless we remove those applications. However, sometimes we may forgot which account we used to install an application from Google Play Store.

My question is that is there any other way to switch between the accounts?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market/4995#4995