# How to Create Additional Google Play Account Under 1 Google Account?

Tags: google-play-store, sync, google-account

I have just set up new Google Account on my tablet that uses new Google Play account. I want to add another Google Account that I use **as main that already has history of apps I bought** in the past and payment method associated with it.

So instead of using new Google Play account with no track record and bought apps, I want to remove it from existing Google Account and **link to it established Google Play account**.

How to do that without adding another Google Account to device only to have everything synced and mixed up? After all this is short term purpose because after adding apps I already bought, will mean removing that Google Account and switching back to previous. What if I want to download paid application again? Here we go again..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/how-to-change-the-account-for-android-market)

Comment: Question there deals with 2 Google Accounts and my question is about 1 Google Account.

Comment: So you want to move your Google Play purchases/history from one account to another?

Comment: I don't know if you literally refer to this as you described, but my point is to replace Google Play account on Google Account with different established Google Play account that I has many apps I bought in past so I can use those on this tablet with new Google Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very strange use case, and Dan Hulme's duplicate suggestion is actually correct.

If you want to use the apps from an OLD account, you need to add the OLD account, switch to the OLD account, and install the apps through the OLD account. Then, you switch back to the NEW account, and remove the OLD account. If you want to install a new app from the OLD account, you need to repeat the same procedure.

As I said, you have a very strange use case, and this is the only workaround. If what you wanted were possible, it would be open to abuse. You could share the account to several people, and let them install apps using that account.

EDIT #1: As per Izzy, removing the OLD account can break the installed apps, as the license checks will fail. So, best to keep both OLD and NEW accounts, but disable the sync on the OLD account (as you suggested).

Comment: You have to add that, as soon the "old account" is removed, paid apps associated with it might stop working – as the license check fails.

Comment: Good point @Izzy

Comment: **GeffChang** The only solution is to have 2 Google Accounts but disable every sync on old account so no data will be downloaded to table I want to share with mom. This allows me to choose old account in Google Play and use it while all else is synced to table from new Google Account.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for pointing that out. I wondered too. Added your comment into the answer.

Comment: @geffchang note my conjunctive ("might"). Not all actually do. Check whether they request the `vending.CHECK_LICENSE` (Google Play license check) permission. If they do, they are likely to fail with the associated account being unavailable (maybe not instantly, but whenever they check next). If they don't, chances are good they keep running (but won't receive updates). I'm even using some of the latter category on my "without Google" devices (so no Google account available at all) for quite a while. Conclusion remains the same in most cases ;)