# Change android Jelly Bean google account with no data loss

Tags: google-account

How to do it?

What I'm doing:

1. add new account in phone settings
2. sync new account
3. remove old one

Is that correct?

Android Jelly Bean version.

Comment: That should be correct. If unsure, you can simply leave the old account and make the new one the default. You will want to do that especially if you're using apps you've bought with the old one, as those are bound to it. Also see: [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4955/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Why not make your comment an answer? Seems about right to me.

Comment: @Ankush because I'm not 100% sure about #3 (or how to put it precisely). Though I don't thing OP will still be on Android 2.x (where account removal would remove associated calendar/contact data), and with 4.x+ it *should* work that way, I've not verified it myself (my devices are de-googlified) or have a source to rely on. But alright, I could state that in an answer :) This way OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the correct steps. Up to step #2 I can say so with certainty, while I don't want to give guarantees for step #3:

- on Android 2.x, removing a Google account also removed associated calendar/contact data. You didn't specify which Android version you're asking about, but assuming Android 4.x or higher this no longer should happen. However, I've not verified that myself (my devices run without Google apps, so I cannot verify even).
- if you've used that account to buy apps, those apps might no longer run with the account removed (they are bound to the account), and you definitely can no longer update them.

So instead of removing the old account, you might wish to simply make the new one the "default account". For that, please refer to [How to change the account for Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4955/16575)